# I have massive memory leak with AzureKinect Dk camera

Tags: python, image, python-multithreading, pyside6, azurekinect

I'm going to create a streaming program using 'ibaiGorodo/pyKinectAzure'.
Images need to be received from the device on a frame basis,
but memory leakage occurs when images are received.

after that, Memory leakage occurs again when using 'fromImage()' in pyside.

It seems that the images in get_images are not returned and are being stacked in memory somewhere.

how can i solve this problem?

```
import threading
import sys
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import pyAzKinct # using this library: https://github.com/ibaiGorordo/pyKinectAzure
from PySide6.QtGui import *
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
import psutil


class GUI_interface(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GUI_interface,self).__init__()

        self.running = False
        self.setWindowTitle('test')

        self.setFixedSize(700, 700)

        self.component_init()
        self.component_method()
        self.show()

    def component_init(self):
        # quit process button
        self.quit_btn = QPushButton('Q  u  i  t', self)
        self.quit_btn.setGeometry(1250, 150, 120, 50)
        self.quit_btn.move(20, 620)

        # start screen1 with black image
        self.img1 = cv.imread('img1.png')
        self.img1 = cv.cvtColor(self.img1, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        qImg1 = QImage(self.img1, self.img1.shape[1], self.img1.shape[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
        self.pixmap1 = QPixmap.fromImage(qImg1)
        self.label1 = QLabel(self)
        self.label1.setPixmap(self.pixmap1)
        self.label1.resize(600, 600)
        self.label1.move(20, 20)

        self.camera = pyAzKinct.transfer_img(0, "master")

    def component_method(self):
        memory_usage("pre-start")
        self.start()
        self.quit_btn.clicked.connect(self.onExit)


    def run(self):
        while True:
            memory_usage("screen Threading")
            img1 = pyAzKinct.get_combine_images(self.camera)  # Main problem
            memory_usage("check1-1")
            crop_img1 = img1[236:844,656:1264]
            memory_usage("check1-2")
            crop_img1 = cv.cvtColor(crop_img1, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            memory_usage("check1-3")
            data1 = QByteArray(crop_img1.tobytes())
            memory_usage("check1-4")
            qImg1 = QImage(data1, crop_img1.shape[1], crop_img1.shape[0], QImage.Format_RGB888) 
            memory_usage("check1-5")
            pImg1 = QPixmap.fromImage(qImg1) #second problem
            memory_usage("check1-6")
            self.label1.setPixmap(pImg1) # apply image
            memory_usage("check1-7")
            self.label1.update()  # refreshing image
            memory_usage("check1-8")

    def stop(self):
        self.camera.capture_release()
        print("stoped..")

    def start(self):
        th = threading.Thread(target=self.run)
        th.daemon = True
        th.start()
        print("started..")

    def onExit(self):
        print("exit")
        self.stop()
        QCoreApplication.instance().quit()

def memory_usage(message: str = 'debug'):
    # current process RAM usage
    p = psutil.Process()
    rss = p.memory_info().rss / 2 ** 20 # Bytes to MB
    print(f"[{message}] memory usage: {rss: 10.5f} MB")





if __name__ == '__main__':
    cv.imwrite('img1.png', np.zeros((600, 600), dtype=np.uint8))

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    test=GUI_interface()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

and this is the log of memory usage:

```
[pre-start] memory usage:  128.82422 MB
[screen Threading] memory usage:  128.87891 MBstarted..

[get_images 1] memory usage:  140.22656 MB
[get_images handle] memory usage:  162.60156 MB
[get_images color] memory usage:  162.66406 MB
[get_images depth] memory usage:  217.75391 MB
[get_images trans] memory usage:  241.04688 MB
[get_images combine] memory usage:  247.01562 MB
[check1-1] memory usage:  239.10156 MB
[check1-2] memory usage:  239.10156 MB
[check1-3] memory usage:  240.16016 MB
[check1-4] memory usage:  241.22656 MB
[check1-5] memory usage:  241.23047 MB
[check1-6] memory usage:  242.66016 MB
[check1-7] memory usage:  242.66016 MB
[check1-8] memory usage:  242.66406 MB
[screen Threading] memory usage:  242.66406 MB
[get_images 1] memory usage:  242.66406 MB
[get_images handle] memory usage:  242.66406 MB
[get_images color] memory usage:  242.66406 MB
[get_images depth] memory usage:  288.49609 MB
[get_images trans] memory usage:  295.50000 MB
[get_images combine] memory usage:  301.43750 MB
[check1-1] memory usage:  287.58984 MB
[check1-2] memory usage:  286.53125 MB
[check1-3] memory usage:  287.58984 MB
[check1-4] memory usage:  288.64844 MB
[check1-5] memory usage:  287.58984 MB
[check1-6] memory usage:  289.00391 MB
[check1-7] memory usage:  287.58984 MB
[check1-8] memory usage:  287.58984 MB
[screen Threading] memory usage:  287.58984 MB
[get_images 1] memory usage:  287.58984 MB
[get_images handle] memory usage:  287.58984 MB
[get_images color] memory usage:  287.58984 MB
[get_images depth] memory usage:  306.61719 MB
[get_images trans] memory usage:  311.58594 MB
[get_images combine] memory usage:  317.51953 MB
[check1-1] memory usage:  303.67188 MB
[check1-2] memory usage:  302.61328 MB
[check1-3] memory usage:  303.67188 MB
[check1-4] memory usage:  304.73047 MB
[check1-5] memory usage:  303.67188 MB
[check1-6] memory usage:  305.08594 MB
[check1-7] memory usage:  303.67188 MB
[check1-8] memory usage:  303.67188 MB
[screen Threading] memory usage:  303.67188 MB
[get_images 1] memory usage:  303.67188 MB
[get_images handle] memory usage:  303.67188 MB
[get_images color] memory usage:  303.67188 MB
[get_images depth] memory usage:  324.22656 MB
[get_images trans] memory usage:  329.18359 MB
[get_images combine] memory usage:  335.11719 MB
[check1-1] memory usage:  321.26953 MB
[check1-2] memory usage:  320.21094 MB
[check1-3] memory usage:  321.26953 MB
[check1-4] memory usage:  322.32812 MB
[check1-5] memory usage:  321.26953 MB
[check1-6] memory usage:  322.68359 MB
[check1-7] memory usage:  321.26953 MB
[check1-8] memory usage:  321.26953 MB
[screen Threading] memory usage:  321.26953 MB
[get_images 1] memory usage:  321.26953 MB
[get_images handle] memory usage:  321.26953 MB
[get_images color] memory usage:  321.26953 MB
[get_images depth] memory usage:  340.57812 MB
[get_images trans] memory usage:  346.57031 MB
[get_images combine] memory usage:  353.50781 MB
[check1-1] memory usage:  339.66016 MB
[check1-2] memory usage:  338.60156 MB
[check1-3] memory usage:  339.66016 MB
[check1-4] memory usage:  340.71875 MB
[check1-5] memory usage:  339.66016 MB
[check1-6] memory usage:  341.07422 MB
[check1-7] memory usage:  339.66016 MB
[check1-8] memory usage:  339.66016 MB
[screen Threading] memory usage:  339.66016 MB
[get_images 1] memory usage:  339.66016 MB
[get_images handle] memory usage:  339.66016 MB
[get_images color] memory usage:  339.66016 MB
[get_images depth] memory usage:  358.10938 MB
[get_images trans] memory usage:  361.62500 MB
[get_images combine] memory usage:  367.55859 MB
[check1-1] memory usage:  352.70703 MB
[check1-2] memory usage:  351.64844 MB
[check1-3] memory usage:  352.70703 MB
[check1-4] memory usage:  353.76562 MB
[check1-5] memory usage:  352.70703 MB
[check1-6] memory usage:  354.12109 MB
[check1-7] memory usage:  352.70703 MB
[check1-8] memory usage:  352.70703 MB
[screen Threading] memory usage:  352.70703 MB
[get_images 1] memory usage:  352.70703 MB
[get_images handle] memory usage:  352.70703 MB
[get_images color] memory usage:  352.70703 MB
[get_images depth] memory usage:  369.07031 MB
[get_images trans] memory usage:  374.06250 MB
[get_images combine] memory usage:  379.99609 MB
[check1-1] memory usage:  366.14844 MB
[check1-2] memory usage:  365.08984 MB
[check1-3] memory usage:  366.14844 MB
[check1-4] memory usage:  367.20703 MB
[check1-5] memory usage:  366.14844 MB
[check1-6] memory usage:  367.56250 MB
[check1-7] memory usage:  366.14844 MB
[check1-8] memory usage:  366.14844 MB
[screen Threading] memory usage:  366.14844 MB
[get_images 1] memory usage:  366.14844 MB
[get_images handle] memory usage:  366.14844 MB
[get_images color] memory usage:  366.14844 MB
[get_images depth] memory usage:  381.38281 MB
[get_images trans] memory usage:  387.37500 MB
[get_images combine] memory usage:  394.31250 MB
[check1-1] memory usage:  380.46484 MB
[check1-2] memory usage:  379.40625 MB
[check1-3] memory usage:  380.46484 MB
[check1-4] memory usage:  381.52344 MB
[check1-5] memory usage:  380.46484 MB
[check1-6] memory usage:  381.87891 MB
[check1-7] memory usage:  380.46484 MB
[check1-8] memory usage:  380.46484 MB
[screen Threading] memory usage:  380.46484 MB
[get_images 1] memory usage:  380.46484 MB
[get_images handle] memory usage:  380.46484 MB
[get_images color] memory usage:  380.46484 MB
[get_images depth] memory usage:  394.29297 MB
[get_images trans] memory usage:  401.29297 MB
[get_images combine] memory usage:  407.22656 MB
[check1-1] memory usage:  393.37891 MB
[check1-2] memory usage:  392.32031 MB
[check1-3] memory usage:  393.37891 MB
[check1-4] memory usage:  394.43750 MB
[check1-5] memory usage:  393.37891 MB
[check1-6] memory usage:  394.79297 MB
[check1-7] memory usage:  393.37891 MB
[check1-8] memory usage:  393.37891 MB
[screen Threading] memory usage:  393.37891 MB
[get_images 1] memory usage:  393.37891 MB
[get_images handle] memory usage:  393.37891 MB
[get_images color] memory usage:  393.37891 MB
[get_images depth] memory usage:  408.21484 MB
[get_images trans] memory usage:  414.20703 MB
[get_images combine] memory usage:  419.13672 MB
[check1-1] memory usage:  405.28906 MB
[check1-2] memory usage:  404.23047 MB
[check1-3] memory usage:  405.28906 MB
[check1-4] memory usage:  406.34766 MB
[check1-5] memory usage:  405.28906 MB
[check1-6] memory usage:  406.70312 MB
[check1-7] memory usage:  405.28906 MB
[check1-8] memory usage:  405.28906 MB
[screen Threading] memory usage:  405.28906 MB
[get_images 1] memory usage:  405.28906 MB
[get_images handle] memory usage:  405.28906 MB
[get_images color] memory usage:  405.28906 MB
[get_images depth] memory usage:  421.28516 MB
[get_images trans] memory usage:  426.21484 MB
[get_images combine] memory usage:  433.15234 MB
[check1-1] memory usage:  419.30469 MB
[check1-2] memory usage:  418.24609 MB
[check1-3] memory usage:  419.30469 MB
[check1-4] memory usage:  420.36328 MB
[check1-5] memory usage:  419.30469 MB
[check1-6] memory usage:  420.71875 MB
[check1-7] memory usage:  419.30469 MB
[check1-8] memory usage:  419.30469 MB
[screen Threading] memory usage:  419.30469 MB
[get_images 1] memory usage:  419.30469 MB
[get_images handle] memory usage:  419.30469 MB
[get_images color] memory usage:  419.30469 MB
[get_images depth] memory usage:  433.71484 MB
[get_images trans] memory usage:  440.71484 MB
[get_images combine] memory usage:  446.64844 MB
[check1-1] memory usage:  432.80078 MB
[check1-2] memory usage:  431.74219 MB
[check1-3] memory usage:  432.80078 MB
[check1-4] memory usage:  433.85938 MB
[check1-5] memory usage:  432.80078 MB
[check1-6] memory usage:  434.21484 MB
[check1-7] memory usage:  432.80078 MB
[check1-8] memory usage:  432.80078 MB
[screen Threading] memory usage:  432.80078 MB
[get_images 1] memory usage:  432.80078 MB
[get_images handle] memory usage:  432.80078 MB
[get_images color] memory usage:  432.80078 MB
[get_images depth] memory usage:  449.04688 MB
[get_images trans] memory usage:  455.03906 MB
[get_images combine] memory usage:  459.96875 MB
[check1-1] memory usage:  446.12109 MB
[check1-2] memory usage:  445.06250 MB
[check1-3] memory usage:  446.12109 MB
[check1-4] memory usage:  447.17969 MB
[check1-5] memory usage:  446.12109 MB
[check1-6] memory usage:  447.53516 MB
[check1-7] memory usage:  446.12109 MB
[check1-8] memory usage:  446.12109 MB
[screen Threading] memory usage:  446.12109 MB
[get_images 1] memory usage:  446.12109 MB
[get_images handle] memory usage:  446.12109 MB
[get_images color] memory usage:  446.12109 MB
[get_images depth] memory usage:  461.46875 MB
[get_images trans] memory usage:  466.45703 MB
[get_images combine] memory usage:  472.39062 MB
[check1-1] memory usage:  458.54297 MB
[check1-2] memory usage:  457.48438 MB
[check1-3] memory usage:  458.54297 MB
[check1-4] memory usage:  459.60156 MB
[check1-5] memory usage:  458.54297 MB
[check1-6] memory usage:  459.95703 MB
[check1-7] memory usage:  458.54297 MB
[check1-8] memory usage:  458.54297 MB
[screen Threading] memory usage:  458.54297 MB
[get_images 1] memory usage:  458.54297 MB
[get_images handle] memory usage:  458.54297 MB
[get_images color] memory usage:  458.54297 MB
[get_images depth] memory usage:  473.82422 MB
[get_images trans] memory usage:  479.81641 MB
[get_images combine] memory usage:  486.75391 MB
[check1-1] memory usage:  472.90625 MB
[check1-2] memory usage:  471.84766 MB
[check1-3] memory usage:  472.90625 MB
[check1-4] memory usage:  473.96484 MB
[check1-5] memory usage:  472.90625 MB
[check1-6] memory usage:  474.32031 MB
[check1-7] memory usage:  472.90625 MB
[check1-8] memory usage:  472.90625 MB
[screen Threading] memory usage:  472.90625 MB
[get_images 1] memory usage:  472.90625 MB
[get_images handle] memory usage:  472.90625 MB
[get_images color] memory usage:  472.90625 MB
[get_images depth] memory usage:  487.07031 MB
[get_images trans] memory usage:  494.06641 MB
[get_images combine] memory usage:  498.99609 MB
[check1-1] memory usage:  485.14844 MB
[check1-2] memory usage:  484.08984 MB
[check1-3] memory usage:  485.14844 MB
[check1-4] memory usage:  486.20703 MB
[check1-5] memory usage:  485.14844 MB
[check1-6] memory usage:  486.56250 MB
[check1-7] memory usage:  485.14844 MB
[check1-8] memory usage:  485.14844 MB
[screen Threading] memory usage:  485.14844 MB
[get_images 1] memory usage:  485.14844 MB
[get_images handle] memory usage:  485.14844 MB
[get_images color] memory usage:  485.14844 MB
[get_images depth] memory usage:  501.31250 MB
[get_images trans] memory usage:  506.30078 MB
[get_images combine] memory usage:  512.23438 MB
[check1-1] memory usage:  498.38672 MB
[check1-2] memory usage:  497.32812 MB
[check1-3] memory usage:  498.38672 MB
[check1-4] memory usage:  499.44531 MB
[check1-5] memory usage:  498.38672 MB
[check1-6] memory usage:  499.80078 MB
[check1-7] memory usage:  498.38672 MB
[check1-8] memory usage:  498.38672 MB
[screen Threading] memory usage:  498.38672 MB
[get_images 1] memory usage:  498.38672 MB
[get_images handle] memory usage:  498.38672 MB
[get_images color] memory usage:  498.38672 MB
[get_images depth] memory usage:  514.39453 MB
[get_images trans] memory usage:  521.33203 MB
[get_images combine] memory usage:  526.26172 MB
[check1-1] memory usage:  512.41406 MB
[check1-2] memory usage:  511.35547 MB
[check1-3] memory usage:  512.41406 MB
[check1-4] memory usage:  513.47266 MB
[check1-5] memory usage:  512.41406 MB
[check1-6] memory usage:  513.82812 MB
[check1-7] memory usage:  512.41406 MB
[check1-8] memory usage:  512.41406 MB
[screen Threading] memory usage:  512.41406 MB
[get_images 1] memory usage:  512.41406 MB
[get_images handle] memory usage:  512.41406 MB
[get_images color] memory usage:  512.41406 MB
[get_images depth] memory usage:  528.38281 MB
[get_images trans] memory usage:  534.31641 MB
[get_images combine] memory usage:  540.25000 MB
[check1-1] memory usage:  526.40234 MB
[check1-2] memory usage:  525.34375 MB
[check1-3] memory usage:  526.40234 MB
[check1-4] memory usage:  527.46094 MB
[check1-5] memory usage:  526.40234 MB
[check1-6] memory usage:  527.81641 MB
[check1-7] memory usage:  526.40234 MB
[check1-8] memory usage:  526.40234 MB
[screen Threading] memory usage:  526.40234 MB
[get_images 1] memory usage:  526.40234 MB
[get_images handle] memory usage:  526.40234 MB
[get_images color] memory usage:  526.40234 MB
[get_images depth] memory usage:  540.32422 MB
[get_images trans] memory usage:  546.25781 MB
[get_images combine] memory usage:  553.19531 MB
[check1-1] memory usage:  539.34766 MB
[check1-2] memory usage:  538.28906 MB
[check1-3] memory usage:  539.34766 MB
[check1-4] memory usage:  540.40625 MB
[check1-5] memory usage:  539.34766 MB
[check1-6] memory usage:  540.76172 MB
[check1-7] memory usage:  539.34766 MB
[check1-8] memory usage:  539.34766 MB
[screen Threading] memory usage:  539.34766 MB
[get_images 1] memory usage:  539.34766 MB
[get_images handle] memory usage:  539.34766 MB
[get_images color] memory usage:  539.34766 MB
[get_images depth] memory usage:  554.52734 MB
[get_images trans] memory usage:  559.48438 MB
[get_images combine] memory usage:  565.41797 MB
[check1-1] memory usage:  555.17969 MB
[check1-2] memory usage:  554.12109 MB
[check1-3] memory usage:  555.48438 MB
[check1-4] memory usage:  553.63281 MB
[check1-5] memory usage:  552.57422 MB
[check1-6] memory usage:  553.98828 MB
[check1-7] memory usage:  552.57422 MB
[check1-8] memory usage:  552.57422 MB
[screen Threading] memory usage:  552.57422 MB
[get_images 1] memory usage:  552.57422 MB
[get_images handle] memory usage:  552.57422 MB
[get_images color] memory usage:  552.57422 MB
[get_images depth] memory usage:  566.28906 MB
[get_images trans] memory usage:  572.22266 MB
[get_images combine] memory usage:  579.16016 MB
[check1-1] memory usage:  565.31250 MB
[check1-2] memory usage:  564.25391 MB
[check1-3] memory usage:  565.31250 MB
[check1-4] memory usage:  566.37109 MB
[check1-5] memory usage:  565.31250 MB
[check1-6] memory usage:  566.72656 MB
[check1-7] memory usage:  565.31250 MB
[check1-8] memory usage:  565.31250 MB
[screen Threading] memory usage:  565.31250 MB
[get_images 1] memory usage:  565.31250 MB
[get_images handle] memory usage:  565.31250 MB
[get_images color] memory usage:  565.31250 MB
[get_images depth] memory usage:  579.51562 MB
[get_images trans] memory usage:  586.51172 MB
[get_images combine] memory usage:  592.44531 MB
[check1-1] memory usage:  578.59766 MB
[check1-2] memory usage:  577.53906 MB
[check1-3] memory usage:  578.59766 MB
[check1-4] memory usage:  579.65625 MB
[check1-5] memory usage:  578.59766 MB
[check1-6] memory usage:  580.01172 MB
[check1-7] memory usage:  578.59766 MB
[check1-8] memory usage:  578.59766 MB
[screen Threading] memory usage:  578.59766 MB
[get_images 1] memory usage:  578.59766 MB
[get_images handle] memory usage:  578.59766 MB
[get_images color] memory usage:  578.59766 MB
[get_images depth] memory usage:  592.60156 MB
[get_images trans] memory usage:  598.03906 MB
[get_images combine] memory usage:  603.97266 MB
[check1-1] memory usage:  590.12500 MB
[check1-2] memory usage:  589.06641 MB
[check1-3] memory usage:  590.12500 MB
[check1-4] memory usage:  591.18359 MB
[check1-5] memory usage:  590.12500 MB
[check1-6] memory usage:  591.53906 MB
[check1-7] memory usage:  590.12500 MB
[check1-8] memory usage:  590.12500 MB
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre], add more details and also embed the log in the post by better explaining the procedure (if more text is provide, the code warning will not be triggered).

Comment: @musicamante i fix this post. please re-check this post

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot test the given module, but I can see at least three important problems in your code: 1. we don't know from where `get_images` comes from and what it does; 2. UI elements should **NEVER** be accessed from an external thread: in order to access (especially if setting properties, like a label `setPixmap`), you should use a QThread and possibly custom signals that are connected to the functions that *actually* access those widgets; 3. QPixmap is **not** thread safe, so they could only be used in the main thread.

Comment: @musicamante but on this code, thread can access to UI element(label)

Comment: The fact that it can **in this case** is completely irrelevant: it only means that you're "lucky" with your OS and system configuration. Move to another computer, another python version, different system conditions or even try to build binaries: best case scenario, you'll see drawing artifacts, worst case, your program will crash. Do a simple research, you'll see that there's absolutely no resource, post, answer that will not tell you that directly accessing UI elements from another thread is wrong, unreliable and safe. UI elements are **not** thread safe.